# Get reference to currently active HTMLElement

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have an Angular 2 and Typescript project, and I want to clear all focus on the page on a specific click.

Right now I am just using `document.activeElement` to get the currently active element, and then calling `.blur()` on it.  However this is not symantically correct, and of course TypeScript is throwing a fit about it (and rightfully so).

Is there any way I can accomplish the same thing, but ensure that I am referencing an `HTMLElement` instead of `Element` so I can keep things typed correctly?

Basically I am calling a function to close all sub-menus when A) The sub-nav is clicked and the menu item clicked is already open, and B) When the document is clicked anywhere that's not a menu item.

Here is the function that is called:

```
closeMenus = function(){
    for (var i=0, j=this.openElements.length; i<j; i++){
        this.openElements[i] = false;
    };

    document.activeElement.blur();
};
```

This gives the error:

```
Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'Element'
```

Which is absolutely correct, it exists on `HTMLElement`. However if I add this line:

```
console.log(document.activeElement instanceof HTMLElement);
```

This returns true. So I am extremely confused about exactly what TypeScript wants here?

Comment: Wouldn't the click itself clear the activeElement?

Comment: not if the click itself is on the element that has focus (like a button or link)

Comment: thx, now I get you :-) What does typescript complain about?

Comment: "Property 'Blur' does not exist on type 'Element'".  Which it doesn't, it only exists on `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inject a `Renderer` into your component/directive.

Get a hold of any `elementRef` (for example your button or link).

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){
}
```

then in your handler function:

```
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
     this.elRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.activeElement, 'blur');
```

Comment: Apparently creating a reference to `document.activeElement`, doing a sanity check for `instanceof HTMLElement`, and then applying blur also makes it happy. However I like this answer better. Thank you.

Comment: For me this works too `if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    document.activeElement.blur();
                }`

Answer (score 25):

The activeElement of the document can be any Element, not just an HTMLElement.  At compile time the compiler does not know what type the element will be.  Hence, if you surround the call with an instanceof check, the compiler knows the activeElement *has* to be an HTMLElement for the code to execute and allows the reference.

```
if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLElement) {
  document.activeElement.blur();
}
```

This approach does not require you to jump through hoops of getting different Angular bindings to execute the method that is already available to you.  Less code and less dependencies!

Comment: This works great! If I could upvote it once for every second I spent on this issue, your reputation would rival Jon Skeet's.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @brian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54933808/1852005), since `document.activeElement` might end up matching something you **don't** want to match (e.g. if the user had quickly clicked another input), you might want to be more specific with your selection.

For example, for a checkbox, you would want something like:

```js
const toggle = document.activeElement;
if (toggle instanceof HTMLInputElement && toggle.type === 'checkbox') {
    toggle.blur();
}
```

See here for other possible types:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input